# Automation Google Play Music playlist scroll with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

So I trying to automate the scrolling of my google play music playlist but its not picking up and I don't what other solutions to use. Normal scrolling like on stack overflow works but I think that Google Music webapp uses something different. So here is my my code so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r"C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\puom7wwz.default-1468625172145")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe',firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://play.google.com/music/listen?u=1#/pl/AMaBXymw0YGY7Y-z1B-FdrwkDCm7WdO_kyK4x4xQqn_vZsg56-VzwjsRKaQPypMs88oIKHn4qZd5aDbFbh5ojt6DpoZZCyHgCA%3D%3D")
driver.find_element_by_id("gb_70").click()

time.sleep(2)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'William Thomas')]").click()
time.sleep(2)

password_field = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password_field.clear()
password_field.send_keys("IcewindDale1995%")
password_field.send_keys(u'\ue007') #unicode for enter key
time.sleep(10)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370208/clicking-on-link-through-google-with-selenium-web-driver")

#driver.find_element_by_id("gba_70").click()
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
time.sleep(10)

#driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('descriptionWrapper').focus();")
#time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 400)")
# i = 0
# while i<1000:
#         scroll = driver.find_element_by_id('descriptionWrapper').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
#         i+=1
driver.find_element_by_id("gba_70").click()

with open('page1.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fid:
    fid.write(str(soup))
driver.close()
```

Edit:

There is no scrolling taking place with that code but it works on the Stack overflow website. 
Anyone with a solution?

Comment: What is the problem? What is happening?

Comment: Nothing is happening. There is no scrolling that is taking place.

Comment: Did u try putting higher values than `400` and scroll to takes `begin` to `end` you might change the first input as well if you want to scroll a second time.

Comment: Yes I tried that even made y = 40000 but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Google Play Music Player on itself does not scroll, you need to have the browser focus on the internal scrollable element, something along the lines of this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#music-content > div.detail-view.g-content.view-transition').click()
```

Hope this answer serves you well!